# Find the exact occurence of a string in HTML file

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I would like to find the count of Exact match of string
Let suppose string is  'My Computer'. I want to find it,s occurrence in string

This is My computer,this is a good Computer,
this is my Computer,this is my Computers

So at end I shall get Count 2 ,

I have tried the following formula with 'mykeyWord' as string to be found.

```
int strength = (innerDocument.DocumentNode.InnerText.Length - innerDocument.DocumentNode.InnerText.ToLower().Replace(mykeyWord.ToLower(), "").Length) / mykeyWord.Length;
```

But it will also count strings like 'my Computers' that is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect place to use regular expressions, just as you tagged your post:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\\b" + Regex.Escape(mykeyWord) + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
int count = re.Matches(innerDocument.DocumentNode.InnerText).Count;
```

Comment: Will you please explain this Regex pattern.

Comment: @ZainAli: `\b` matches a word boundary, i.e. anything that isn't a word. Punctuation, spaces, etcetera. It sandwiches your escaped keyword in between there to match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression `[^A-z](my computer)[^A-z]` This matches 'my computer' but not if it's before or after 'A to Z'. To make the regex search case insensitive use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

**Edit**
minitech's answer using word boundaries is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
int FindCount(string keyword, string input)
    {
        if (input.Contains(keyword))
        {
            int count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var c in input)
            {
                if (c == keyword[i])
                    i++;
                else
                    i = 0;
                if (i == keyword.Length)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```